# How to handle long audio clips in machine learning?

Tags: audio, machine-learning, deep-learning

What do people do when handling long audio clip(2min-5min, 44.1khz) in machine learning tasks such as music classification?

Is there any methods except downsampling that would help to reduce the dimensionality of audio data?

Comment: You're going to need to be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you are extracting frequency features like spectrogram or MFCC and then you classify them. They have less values than raw audio, so they are easier to analyze.

You can find some visualizations of spectrograms and MFCC here (related to speech, but scales):

https://www.kaggle.com/davids1992/speech-visualization-and-exploration

Note that pooling somehow reduces dimensionality of data in CNN.

So find about spectral analysis. You are rarely working with raw waves, although they are starting to work also, like WaveNet:

https://deepmind.com/blog/wavenet-generative-model-raw-audio/